# Help with ppm calculation

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration

Recently, me and my class had a lab about spectrophotometry, where we try to determine the concentration in ppm of an unknown sample contaminated with manganese.
In the process of calculating this concentration, we have to make a linear regression using the absorbance data from known concentrations in ppm. Me, my classmates and the teacher have conflicting answers about how to calculate the ppm concentration and I wish to confirm if my method is right or wrong. It goes as follows:

Vial 1 has 2 mL of a 0,0008 mol/L solution of manganese, diluted to 100 mL with water. Since 1 ppm = 1 mg/L, the calculation goes as follows:

There are 0,0008 x 0,002 = 0,0000016 moles of manganese in Vial 1, which by the molar mass of manganese (54,938 g/mol) is 0,0000879 grams, which is equivalent to 0,0879008 mg. Since 100 mL = 0,1 L, the ppm concentration is then 0,0879008 mg/0,1 L = 0,879008 ppm. Is this correct?

My teacher and classmates used 1 L instead of 0,1 L in the calculation for reasons I do not know, which makes it 0,0879008 ppm instead.

Comment: Be aware that using of ppm relative unit is strongly discouraged by IUPAC. as it often brings confusion.  Saying 1 ppm means 1 mg/L makes 2 implicit assumptions. 1/ It is implying 1 ppm is related to parts per million in units of mass (can be volume or amount)  2/ It is implying the density of the fluid is 1 kg/L. // The recommended way is, instead of 1 ppm,  explicitly writing 1 mg/L, if it is the case.

Comment: See CH SE META post about [policy for "Am I right?" questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions)